# Is it possible to create a ODBC System DSN from C# using SQLConfigDataSourceW?

Tags: c#, odbc, dsn

I need to create ODBC DSN connections from C# programmatically. I've gotten the following code working, which uses the SQLConfigDataSourceW function to create an ODBC DSN connection.

```
   public class OdbcWrapper
{

    [DllImport("ODBCCP32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SQLConfigDataSourceW(UInt32 hwndParent, RequestFlags fRequest, string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);

    enum RequestFlags : int
    {
        ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1,
        ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2,
        ODBC_REMOVE_DSN = 3,
        ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4,
        ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN = 5,
        ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN = 6,
        ODBC_REMOVE_DEFAULT_DSN = 7
    }

    public bool UpdateDsnServer(string name, string server)
    {
        var flag = RequestFlags.ODBC_ADD_DSN;
        string dsnNameLine = "DSN=" + name;
        string serverLine = "Server=" + server;

        string trusted = "Trusted_Connection=YES";

        string configString = new[] { dsnNameLine, serverLine,trusted }.Aggregate("", (str, line) => str + line + "\0");

        return SQLConfigDataSourceW(0, flag, "SQL Server", configString);
    }
}
```

Which I can the call using:

```
var odbc = new OdbcWrapper();
bool test = odbc.UpdateDsnServer("TEST_DSN_NAME", "TEST_SERVER_NAME");
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
```

This works for `ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1` where a User DSN is created and returns `test = true`, but when I change the flag to `ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4` it returns `test = false` and no System DSN is created, both cases confirmed by checking the ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Comment: See pinvole.  I found two differences between you code and pinvoke 1) The enumeration should be int16 2) You need quotes around filename : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbccp32.SQLConfigDataSource

Comment: If your app can create a User DSN but not a System DSN then it probably doesn't have sufficient permissions to modify that part of the Windows registry. Check the account under which the app is running.

Comment: @GordThompson I agree this seems to be the issue. I The account running the app is an admin and when I checked the registry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC, USERS have Full Control for ODBC and all subkeys.

The other piece I can't make sense of is that I can Create a new System DSN from the ODBC Data Source Administrator using the same server and Integrated Windows authentication. If the permissions here are sufficient, why wouldn't the permissions be sufficient from the C# application?

Comment: ODBC Data Source Administrator can create system DSNs because it requests permissions elevation when starting (did you see UAC's question when started the tool?). Try running your application with elevated permissions too: find your executable file in Explorer, press right mouse button on it and choose "Run as administrator" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the application with elevated permissions allows a system DSN to be created. The code above works as is, but the application was missing the permissions elevation that were requested in the ODBC Data Source Administrator. Once running with the correct permissions, the code replicates the functionality of creating, deleting, and configuring user, file, and system DSNs.